# Backbone.js fetch GET with data

Tags: backbone.js, jqxhr

I have a REST server that takes a query string in the request body of a GET statement.

It's similar to the Parse REST api that does the same.  As seen in the curl statement below.

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: ${APPLICATION_ID}" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ${REST_API_KEY}" \
  -G \
  --data-urlencode 'where={"playerName":"Sean Plott","cheatMode":false}' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore
```

My question is: How do I send a Backbone fetch (essentially a -X GET) with a data string.

Ive tried the following;

```
   fetch: function(options) {
      options = _.extend({data: 'Active is true' }, options);
      return Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.apply(this, arguments);
  }
```

Currently, that appends the string on the URL as parameters as such

http://restserver.com/collection/Customer?Active%20eq%20true

Answer (score 0):

In your collection class, implement the `url` property as a function that returns the URL path plus the query string you want. The query string can be built up from properties stored on your collection instance like `collection.playerName`, etc. This pattern works well for a search query string type use case such as yours.